# How do I fix "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages"?

Tags: apt, dependencies

I have problems downloading and installing several software packages.

This is what I get every time: some broken packages.

```
$ sudo apt install i3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 i3 : Depends: i3-wm (= 4.16.1-1~~xenial1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: i3lock (>= 2.2) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: suckless-tools but it is not installable
      Recommends: i3status (>= 2.3) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: dunst but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My Ubuntu version is 16.04.

As asked for, the contents of */etc/apt/sources.list.d/sur5r-i3.list*:

```
deb https://debian.sur5r.net/i3/ xenial universe
```

Comment: What PPAs are you using?

Comment: I followed the instructions on i3 site.
These:
```/usr/lib/apt/apt-helper download-file https://debian.sur5r.net/i3/pool/main/s/sur5r-keyring/sur5r-keyring_2019.02.01_all.deb keyring.deb SHA256:176af52de1a976f103f9809920d80d02411ac5e763f695327de9fa6aff23f416
# dpkg -i ./keyring.deb
# echo "deb https://debian.sur5r.net/i3/ $(grep '^DISTRIB_CODENAME=' /etc/lsb-release | cut -f2 -d=) universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sur5r-i3.list
# apt update
# apt install i3```
It tells me that I have to have superuser privileges.

Comment: not solving my problem. Thanks anyway

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sur5r-i3.list` It is likely that adding this debian ppa to your system broke the package system.

Comment: For 16.04, use 2016-era packages. Newer packages will have wrong-version dependencies (1.2 instead of 1.1), which is what usually causes "held broken packages" and "you have requested an impossible situation"

Comment: "It tells me that I have to have superuser privileges" suggests that you might be cutting-and-pasting incantations that you perhaps don't fully understand. If so, it might be wise to post a link to those instructions.